# How to Avoid Multiple Ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What I need

> when click event is triggered service call is made then it may call only one time only.

Use case

Dropdown1

Dropdown2

Dropdown3

```
        1. There are three dropdown in html page.
        2. when dropdown 1 is call - ajax call made only 1 time.
        3. when dropwdown 2 is call -ajax call made only 1 time.
        4. when dropwdown 3 is call -ajax call made only 1 time.
```

Now user change dropdown 1.

```
        5. when dropwdown 1 is call -ajax call made only 1 time.
```

Problem occurs

```
        6. Now when dropwdown 2 is call -ajax call made only 2 time.
        7. Now when dropwdown 3 is call -ajax call made only 2 time.
```

similary when we change dropdown 1

```
        count increase by one.
```

Now user change dropdown 1.

```
        8. Now when dropwdown 2 is call -ajax call made only 3 time.
        9. Now when dropwdown 3 is call -ajax call made only 3 time.
```

Js code

> dowpdown 1 has assigned id with dowpdown_1
>
> dowpdown 2 has assigned id with dowpdown_2
>
> dowpdown 3 has assigned id with dowpdown_3

```js
$("#dowpdown_1").change(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'path',
    cache: false,
    data: {
      data
    },
    success: function(html) {
      console.log('dowpdown_1');
      $("#dowpdown_2").change(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'path',
          cache: false,
          data: {
            data
          },
          success: function(html) {
            console.log('dowpdown_2');
          }
        });
      }
      $("#dowpdown_3").change(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'path',
          cache: false,
          data: {
            data
          },
          success: function(html) {
            console.log('dowpdown_3');
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Any solution is most welcome.

Comment: `var called = null; el.onclick = e => if (!called) called = $.ajax(...`

Comment: HI JARED thanks, but can elaborate the solution please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everytime you change the dropdown_1 you are adding a new event to dropdown_2 and dropdown_3 that do the same thing.

It might seem that this is the same event but you are actually binding new change events to your dropdowns.

You can either bind only once the events or if you want your previous structure (seems like cascade functionality but I am not sure) you could use this:

```
$("#dowpdown_2").off().on('change', function () {// do the ajax});

$("#dowpdown_3").off().on('change', function () {// do the ajax});
```

This way everytime you add the new function on the change event you will at least unbind all previous events from it and it won't trigger again. Of course this means that there aren't any other change events that matter to your case because they will be unbinded too.

Else as I said you can just do this

```
$("#dowpdown_1").on('change', function () 
{
    $.ajax({
    url: 'path',
    cache: false,
    data: {data},
    success: function (html) 
    {
      console.log('dowpdown_1');
    }
});

$("#dowpdown_2").on('change', function () {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'path',
        cache: false,
        data: {data},
        success: function (html) 
        {
            console.log('dowpdown_2');
        }
});
$("#dowpdown_3").on('change', function () {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'path',
    cache: false,
    data: {data},
    success: function (html) 
    {
        console.log('dowpdown_3');

    }
});
```

Comment: But the problem this code doesnot solved problem  if ajax 2, ajax 3 are dependent on ajax 1 call.

Comment: Ok I was editing my answer. The jquery off should do what you need.

Comment: Glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 2):

everytime your ajax is completed, your callback attaches a new event to your other 2 dropdowns. That means every time you bind an event inside of an ajax callback you have to care if an element exists or it will be new created.

TLDR adding .unbind in front of your event should fix this

```
$("#dowpdown_2").unbind().change(function () {
....
})
```